# Exit gracefully from Python after SIGKILL

Tags: python, signals

The problem being that SIGKILL cannot be caught, is there a way to ensure that a block of code gets executed on program termination? I have a process that starts five subprocesses and changes the state of platform hardware - it handles SIGTERM and SIGINT, however a SIGKILL will kill the main process while the subprocesses continue to run. Is there a way to always execute a cleanup or do I have to accept that SIGKILL will leave the computer in a 'corrupt' state?

Comment: I don't think you can handle `SIGKILL`

Comment: I don't think either. Otherwise there would be no point in having it. It's supposed to kill process at any cost, not wait for clean exit.

Comment: I understand that, but it does not effectively kill my program as it is  still executing with respect to the children processes that continue to run

Answer (score 1):

`SIGKILL` cannot be handled.  This signal used for critical cases where you dont want the program to be able to ignore the signal and you want to force it to be killed.
`SIGTERM` is the complement, this need to be use when you want to let the program cleanup before it closed

for more information you can read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#Handling_signals